# How to calculate and return result of specific R function in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use a R function in my shiny app but in vain...
This function is called "procedure_finale_shiny" and takes many arguments :

```
procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))
```

and it returns a list of two elements.

And for information :

```
str(formals(procedure_finale_shiny))
```

returns

```
Dotted pair list of 7
 $ alpha_1      : symbol 
 $ alpha_2      : symbol 
 $ alpha_3      : symbol 
 $ alpha_4      : symbol 
 $ alpha_5      : symbol 
 $ choix_ratios : symbol 
 $ choix_modeles: symbol
```

I would like that the shiny app calculate and returns those 2 elements. The arguments (parameters) would be chosen by the user (but not the database for now just the parameters called "Choix des paramètres" in the UI).

I'm for the moment just working on the first tabPanel (1st page of the app).

Here is my user interface :  https://milesfrancois.shinyapps.io/shiny/

And here is my code (shiny app) :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinythemes)
library(SwimmeR)
library(rsconnect)


button_color_css <- "
#DivCompClear, #FinderClear, #EnterTimes{
/* Change the background color of the update button
to blue. */
background: DodgerBlue;

/* Change the text size to 15 pixels. */
font-size: 15px;
}"

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  #Navbar structure for UI
  navbarPage("Selection de modeles", theme = shinytheme("slate"),
             tabPanel("Programme", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("spinner"),
                      tags$style(button_color_css),
                      # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          h3("Chargement des donnees"),

                          fileInput("file", "Charger un jeu de donnees :"),

                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "DataExemple",
                                             label = "Utiliser les donnees de base :",
                                             choices = c("Donnees de base" = "D1")),

                          hr(),

                          actionButton(inputId = "DeleteData", label = "Supprimer les donnees", icon = icon("trash-alt")),

                          hr(),

                          h3("Implementation de la procedure de selection"),
                          #shinythemes::themeSelector(),


                          # Select modele
                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ModeleFinder",
                                             label = "Choix des modele(s):",
                                             choices = c("Modele 1" = c(1), "Modele 2 " = c(2),"Modele 3 " = c(3),"Modele 4 " = c(4)),
                                             selected = "M1"),

                          hr(),


                          # Select ratio 1
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio1",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 1",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),

                          # Select ratio 2
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio2",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 2",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),

                          # Select ratio 3
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio3",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 3",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),

                          # Select ratio 4
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio4",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 4",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),

                          # Select ratio 5
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio5",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 5",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),

                          hr(),
                          hr(),

                          # Select alpha 1
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha1",
                                      label = "Importance du ratio",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),

                          # Select alpha 2
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha2",
                                      label = "Importance de l'erreur d'apprentissage",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),

                          # Select alpha 3
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha3",
                                      label = "Importance de l'erreur test",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),

                          # Select alpha 4
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha4",
                                      label = "Importance du temps de calcul",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),

                          # Select alpha 5
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha5",
                                      label = "Importance de la complexite du modele",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),

                          hr(),
                          actionButton(inputId = "calculate", label = "Calculer", icon = icon("check")),
                          hr(),

                          h3("Sauvegarder les resultats"),

                          selectInput(inputId = "Export1",
                                      label = "Choisir le format",
                                      choices = c("csv", "texte","PDF","xlsx","SPSS","SAS","Stata"),
                                      selected = "csv"),


                          downloadButton("downloadData1", "Download")

                        ),

                        mainPanel(

                          ### add your style inline css values here

                          ### added a line of code here too `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover `###
                          tags$style(HTML("
                                          .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
                                          color: #ffffff;
                                          }
                                          ### ADD THIS HERE ###
                                          .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#ffffff !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}

                                          ###To change text and background color of the `Select` box ###
                                          .dataTables_length select {
                                          color: #0E334A;
                                          background-color: #0E334A
                                          }

                                          ###To change text and background color of the `Search` box ###
                                          .dataTables_filter input {
                                          color: #0E334A;
                                          background-color: #0E334A
                                          }

                                          thead {
                                          color: #ffffff;
                                          }

                                          tbody {
                                          color: #000000;
                                          }

                                          "


                    )
  ),

                          h4("Tableau de resultats"),
                          dataTableOutput("tab_res"),

                          hr(),


                          h4("Meilleur modele"),
                          dataTableOutput("best_mod")


                        )

                      )
             ),  

             tabPanel("Code & Donnees", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("database"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          h3("Affichage des donnees"),

                          radioButtons(inputId = "Display1",
                                       label = "",
                                       choices = c("preview", "str","summary"),
                                       selected = "preview"),

                          hr(),

                          h3("Affichage du code"),

                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "CodeR",
                                             label = "",
                                             choices = c("Afficher le code R" = "R1"))

                        ),

                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),

             tabPanel("Graphiques", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("chart-line"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          h3("Choix du modele"),

                          radioButtons(inputId = "Display2",
                                       label = "",
                                       choices = c("Modele 1", "Modele 2","Modele 3","Modele 4"),
                                       selected = "Modele 1"),

                          hr(),

                          h3("Sauvegarder le graphique"),

                          selectInput(inputId = "ExportGraph",
                                      label = "Choisir le format",
                                      choices = c("PNG", "JPEG","BMP"),
                                      selected = "PNG"),

                          downloadButton("downloadData2", "Download")

                        ),

                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),

             navbarMenu("Plus d'informations", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                        tabPanel("ÃƒÂ‰tude", fluid = TRUE,
                                 fluidRow(
                                   column(6,
                                          h4(p("RÃƒÂ©sumÃƒÂ©")),
                                          h5(p("Cette ÃƒÂ©tude a ÃƒÂ©tÃƒÂ© rÃƒÂ©alisÃƒÂ©e au cours d'un stage de fin d'ÃƒÂ©tudes en deuxiÃƒÂ¨me annÃƒÂ©e de Master DSMS (Data Science et ModÃƒÂ©lisation Statistique) ÃƒÂ  l'UniversitÃƒÂ© de Bretagne Sud. Le stage s'est dÃƒÂ©roulÃƒÂ© au sein du LMBA (Laboratoire de MathÃƒÂ©matiques de Bretagne Atlantique) sur une pÃƒÂ©riode de six mois."),
                                             p("Le sujet du stage ÃƒÂ©tait le suivant : Ã‚Â« Automatisation d'une procÃƒÂ©dure de sÃƒÂ©lection de modÃƒÂ¨les dans le cadre du Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es Ã‚Â»."),
                                             p("Au cours d'un projet prÃƒÂ©cÃƒÂ©dent, un outil avait ÃƒÂ©tÃƒÂ© contruit afin d'ajuster un modÃƒÂ¨le (de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es) sur des donnÃƒÂ©es et de collecter certaines informations associÃƒÂ©es ÃƒÂ  celui-ci. L'objectif de notre stage ÃƒÂ©tait donc d'ÃƒÂ©prouver l'outil dÃƒÂ©jÃƒÂ  existant, d'augmenter sa robustesse et son niveau de gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ricitÃƒÂ© et enfin d'automatiser la procÃƒÂ©dure complÃƒÂ¨te de sÃƒÂ©lection de modÃƒÂ¨les."),
                                             p("Cette interface Shiny est en quelque sorte la mise en forme de nos travaux."),
                                             p("Les dÃƒÂ©tails qui sont propres ÃƒÂ  notre programme sont rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ©rencÃƒÂ©s dans l'onglet intitulÃƒÂ© Ã‚Â« DÃƒÂ©tails Ã‚Â».")
                                          )
                                   ),
                                   column(6,
                                          h4(p("Le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es")),
                                          h5(p("Si l'on se rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ¨re aux travaux effectuÃƒÂ©s par FLOURENT (2019) dans le domaine du Smart Farming (l'agriculture de prÃƒÂ©cision), on peut dire que le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est une approche qui se situe ÃƒÂ  mi-chemin entre les approches dÃƒÂ®tes Ã‚Â« Black Box Ã‚Â» et Ã‚Â« White Box Ã‚Â»."),
                                             p("Le type de modÃƒÂ¨le appelÃƒÂ© Ã‚Â« Black Box Ã‚Â» fait en grande partie rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ©rence aux modÃƒÂ¨les classiques du Machine Learning (rÃƒÂ©seaux de neurones .). D'aprÃƒÂ¨s GORCZYCA et al (2018), VALLETTA et al. (2017), MA et al. (2014) et IP et al. (2018), la popularitÃƒÂ© de ces modÃƒÂ¨les peut s'expliquer par leur facilitÃƒÂ© d'utilisation, ainsi que par la diversitÃƒÂ© des problÃƒÂ¨mes pouvant ÃƒÂªtre rÃƒÂ©solus grÃƒÂ¢ce ÃƒÂ  de tels algorithmes. NÃƒÂ©anmoins ces modÃƒÂ¨les contiennent peu de connaissances a priori. Par consÃƒÂ©quent, les outils basÃƒÂ©s sur ce type de modÃƒÂ¨les sont peu informatifs d'un point de vue biologique (TAN et GILBERT (2003), SHAVLIK et al. (1995), HUBBARD et REINHARDT (1998)). Il faut ÃƒÂ©galement noter qu'il est nÃƒÂ©cessaire d'apprendre les paramÃƒÂ¨tres de ces modÃƒÂ¨les ÃƒÂ  partir de beaucoup de donnÃƒÂ©es et ceci dans le but de pallier l'absence d'expertise biologique (DUMPALA et al. (2017))"),
                                             p("ÃƒÂ€ l'inverse, les modÃƒÂ¨les Ã‚Â« White Box Ã‚Â» correspondent ÃƒÂ  des modÃƒÂ¨les mÃƒÂ©canistes rÃƒÂ©alistes (VAZQUEZ-CRUZ et al. (2014)). Si l'on se penche sur les travaux de BASTIANELLI et SAUVANT (1997) et MARTIN et SAUVANT (2010), la construction de modÃƒÂ¨les mÃƒÂ©canistes rÃƒÂ©alistes est une tÃƒÂ¢che complexe menant gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ralement ÃƒÂ  un modÃƒÂ¨le contenant un grand nombre d'ÃƒÂ©quations et de paramÃƒÂ¨tres ÃƒÂ  dÃƒÂ©terminer. Ce type de modÃƒÂ¨le nÃƒÂ©cessite d'avoir beaucoup de connaissances concernant le systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ©."),
                                             p("On cite une nouvelle fois les travaux de FLOURENT : Ã‚Â« Le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es consiste ÃƒÂ  intÃƒÂ©grer des connaissances concernant la dynamique du systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ© via la construction d'un modÃƒÂ¨le mathÃƒÂ©matique et ÃƒÂ  utiliser ensuite des donnÃƒÂ©es pour ajuster les paramÃƒÂ¨tres du modÃƒÂ¨le construit Ã‚Â». On peut aussi reprendre les travaux de FRENOD (2017), ROUSSEAU et NODET (2013), SACKS et al. (2007) et WANG et al. (2010), et dire que le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨les-DonnÃƒÂ©es consiste ÃƒÂ  construire un modÃƒÂ¨le mathÃƒÂ©matique parcimonieux, correspondant ÃƒÂ  une synthÃƒÂ¨se mathÃƒÂ©matique du systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ©.")
                                          )
                                   ))

                        ),

                        tabPanel("DÃƒÂ©tails", fluid = TRUE,
                                 fluidRow(
                                   column(6,
                                          #br(),
                                          h4(p("ModÃƒÂ¨les")),
                                          h5(p("Notre programme comporte trois types de modÃƒÂ¨les et quatre modÃƒÂ¨les diffÃƒÂ©rents. Deux modÃƒÂ¨les de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es (les modÃƒÂ¨les 1 et 2), un modÃƒÂ¨le de type rÃƒÂ©seau de neurones (le modÃƒÂ¨le 3) et un modÃƒÂ¨le de type linÃƒÂ©aire (le modÃƒÂ¨le 4).")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("ParamÃƒÂ¨tres")),
                                          h5(p("Le premier modÃƒÂ¨le de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est composÃƒÂ© de trois paramÃƒÂ¨tres ajustÃƒÂ©s. Le second modÃƒÂ¨le de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est composÃƒÂ© de deux paramÃƒÂ¨tres ajustÃƒÂ©s et d'un paramÃƒÂ¨tre fixe. Le modÃƒÂ¨le de type rÃƒÂ©seau de neurones est composÃƒÂ© de trois couches cachÃƒÂ©es (la premiÃƒÂ¨re et la troisiÃƒÂ¨me couches comportent trois neurones, la deuxiÃƒÂ¨me couche compte six neurones).")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Informations")),
                                          h5(p("Notre outil permet de collecter un certain nombre d'informations sur chacun des modÃƒÂ¨les comme l'erreur d'apprentissage, l'erreur test ou encore le temps de calcul. Certaines de ces informations nous sont utiles pour calculer notre indicateur de comparaison."))

                                          #hr(),

                                   ),
                                   column(6,
                                          #br(),
                                          h4(p("Indicateur")),
                                          h5(p("Notre indicateur de comparaison se base sur cinq informations diffÃƒÂ©rentes, ÃƒÂ  savoir : l'erreur test, l'erreur d'apprentissage, le temps de calcul, la complexitÃƒÂ© du modÃƒÂ¨le et la ratio.")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Programme")),
                                          h5(p("Le programme, sur la base de l'indicateur, renvoie le Ã‚Â« meilleur Ã‚Â» modÃƒÂ¨le ainsi qu'un tableau de rÃƒÂ©sultats avec un certain nombre d'infomations. L'utilisateur a la possibilitÃƒÂ© de sÃƒÂ©lectionner les modÃƒÂ¨les qu'il souhaite comparer, de choisir diffÃƒÂ©rents ratios (taille des donnÃƒÂ©es d'apprentissage et de test) ainsi que les poids associÃƒÂ©s (alphas) aux paramÃƒÂ¨tres de l'indicateur.")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Poids associÃƒÂ©s")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 1 : poids associÃƒÂ© au ratio")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 2 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  l'erreur d'apprentissage")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 3 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  l'erreur test")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 4 : poids associÃƒÂ© au temps de calcul")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 5 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  la complexitÃƒÂ© du modÃƒÂ¨le"))

                                   )
                                 ),
                                 br(),
                                 hr(),
                                 h6(      
                                   p(
                                     a("UniversitÃƒÂ© de Bretagne Sud", 
                                       href = "https://www.univ-ubs.fr/fr/index.html"),
                                     br(),
                                     br(),
                                     a("Laboratoire de MathÃƒÂ©matiques de Bretagne Atlantique", 
                                       href = "http://www.lmba-math.fr/"))),

                                 h6("ConÃƒÂ§u avec",
                                    img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shiny.png", height = "30px"),
                                    "par",
                                    img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray.png", height = "30px"),
                                    ".")
                        )
             )
  )
)



work_dir_3 <- "C:\\Users\\François\\Desktop\\SHINY"
setwd(work_dir_3)
getwd()

source("procedure_finale_shiny.R", local = TRUE)

#res1 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[1]]) 
#res2 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[2]])

server <- function(input, output) {


  result1 <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {

    as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(input$SliderAlpha1,input$SliderAlpha2,input$SliderAlpha3,input$SliderAlpha4,input$SliderAlpha5,c(input$SliderRatio1,input$SliderRatio2,input$SliderRatio3,input$SliderRatio4,input$SliderRatio5,c(input$ModeleFinder)))[[1]])

  })


  result2 <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {

    as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(input$SliderAlpha1,input$SliderAlpha2,input$SliderAlpha3,input$SliderAlpha4,input$SliderAlpha5,c(input$SliderRatio1,input$SliderRatio2,input$SliderRatio3,input$SliderRatio4,input$SliderRatio5,c(input$ModeleFinder)))[[2]])

  })


  output$best_mod <- renderDataTable({

    result2()

  })

  output$tab_res <- renderDataTable({

    result1()

  })



}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right start, but there is no need to calculate it *twice* (and perhaps many reasons to not do that). Try this:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {
    procedure_finale_shiny(
      input$SliderAlpha1, input$SliderAlpha2, input$SliderAlpha3, input$SliderAlpha4, input$SliderAlpha5,
      c(input$SliderRatio1, input$SliderRatio2,input$SliderRatio3, input$SliderRatio4, input$SliderRatio5),
      as.numeric(input$ModeleFinder))
  })

  output$best_mod <- renderTable({ results()[[1]] })
  output$tab_res <- renderTable({ results()[[2]] })
}
```

I'm not familiar with the function (and it does not matter), but if you need `as.data.frame`, that might be more appropriate within `renderDataTable` than within `eventReactive`.

(*Edited* several times to account for problems with the `procedure_finale_shiny` function. Namely, (1) the ratio arguments should be in a vector, and the OP function call was missing a close-paren to group them; and (2) the function's last argument (`choix_modeles`) requires a numeric or integer argument, not the string that shiny is prone to returning from inputs.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It seems that the last 4 arguments `c(input$ModeleFinder)` are not taken into account. I get this message : **"Error : argument "choix_modeles" is missing, with no default"**. My function is defined like that : `procedure_finale_shiny = function(alpha_1,alpha_2,alpha_3,alpha_4,alpha_5,choix_ratios,choix_modeles)`.

Comment: I don't know. Knowing nothing about that function, it's nearly impossible to say for sure. I thought your question is about how to (efficiently) use a single function call in multiple shiny outputs.

Comment: It is a pretty big one and this is why I didn't post it. I called this function with : `source("procedure_finale_shiny.R", local = TRUE)`

Comment: I see that, but to be honest, how you source a function does nothing to help troubleshoot it. It might help if you include at least the *formals* of the function, with `str(formals(procedure_finale_shiny))` (in the question)

Comment: Ok thanks again. Should I post the all function (procedure_finale_shiny) ?

Comment: I think you (or I?) were missing a close-paren after the alphas. See my edit.

Comment: .. I meant a close-paren after the ratios, not the alphas.

Comment: Ok Thanks ! It's almost good. I have a new error message and I'm trying to solve it. If I can't fixed it I will post the error message.

Comment: If it's related to the shiny integration, sure, but otherwise it might be more appropriate to accept this answer and move on to a new question. Over to you. (And be careful: *warning* != *error*.)

Comment: I think it is related.The new error message is this one : **"Error : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"**. It seems that the values of `input$ModeleFinder` are not numeric.

Comment: Yes. See the definition of `choices=` in [`?checkboxGroupInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/checkboxGroupInput.html) where it says: *"The values should be strings; other types (such as logicals and numbers) will be coerced to strings."* See my edit where I use `as.numeric`. If it's always an integer, you can instead use `as.integer`, but I didn't want to assume. (And some functions actually *do* fail with `integer` when it expects `numeric`, to which I almost always file a bug report.)

Comment: Ok It's seems to be good. I have no error message or warning but there are not results. But I have no results and it's look like the actionButton does nothing...