# How to calculate and return result of specific R function in a Shiny app ? (part 2)

Tags: r, shiny

My question is related to this one: [How to calculate and return result of specific R function in a Shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070010/how-to-calculate-and-return-result-of-specific-r-function-in-a-shiny-app/62070419?noredirect=1#62070419)

I am currently working on a shiny app and using an R function to build this app.
And my shiny app seems to work well (no error message) but I have no results...

Here is my UI code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinythemes)
library(SwimmeR)
library(rsconnect)


button_color_css <- "
#DivCompClear, #FinderClear, #EnterTimes{
/* Change the background color of the update button
to blue. */
background: DodgerBlue;

/* Change the text size to 15 pixels. */
font-size: 15px;
}"

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #Navbar structure for UI
  navbarPage("Selection de modeles", theme = shinytheme("slate"),
             tabPanel("Programme", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("spinner"),
                      tags$style(button_color_css),
                      # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          h3("Chargement des donnees"),
                          
                          fileInput("file", "Charger un jeu de donnees :"),
                          
                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "DataExemple",
                                             label = "Utiliser les donnees de base :",
                                             choices = c("Donnees de base" = "D1")),
                          
                          hr(),
                          
                          actionButton(inputId = "DeleteData", label = "Supprimer les donnees", icon = icon("trash-alt")),
                          
                          hr(),
                          
                          h3("Implementation de la procedure de selection"),
                          #shinythemes::themeSelector(),
                          
                          
                          # Select modele
                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ModeleFinder",
                                             label = "Choix des modele(s):",
                                             choices = c("Modele 1" = c(1), "Modele 2 " = c(2),"Modele 3 " = c(3),"Modele 4 " = c(4)),
                                             selected = "M1"),
                          
                          hr(),

                          
                          # Select ratio 1
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio1",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 1",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),
                          
                          # Select ratio 2
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio2",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 2",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),
                          
                          # Select ratio 3
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio3",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 3",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),
                          
                          # Select ratio 4
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio4",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 4",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),
                          
                          # Select ratio 5
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderRatio5",
                                      label = "Choix ratio 5",
                                      min = 0, max = 100, 30
                          ),
                          
                          hr(),
                          hr(),
                          
                          # Select alpha 1
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha1",
                                      label = "Importance du ratio",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),
                          
                          # Select alpha 2
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha2",
                                      label = "Importance de l'erreur d'apprentissage",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),
                          
                          # Select alpha 3
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha3",
                                      label = "Importance de l'erreur test",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),
                          
                          # Select alpha 4
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha4",
                                      label = "Importance du temps de calcul",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),
                          
                          # Select alpha 5
                          sliderInput(inputId = "SliderAlpha5",
                                      label = "Importance de la complexite du modele",
                                      min = 0, max = 1, 0.3
                          ),
                          
                          hr(),
                          actionButton(inputId = "calculate", label = "Calculer", icon = icon("check")),
                          hr(),
                          
                          h3("Sauvegarder les resultats"),
                          
                          selectInput(inputId = "Export1",
                                      label = "Choisir le format",
                                      choices = c("csv", "texte","PDF","xlsx","SPSS","SAS","Stata"),
                                      selected = "csv"),
                          
                          
                          downloadButton("downloadData1", "Download")
                          
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel(
                          
                          ### add your style inline css values here
                          
                          ### added a line of code here too `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover `###
                          tags$style(HTML("
                                          .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
                                          color: #ffffff;
                                          }
                                          ### ADD THIS HERE ###
                                          .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#ffffff !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}
                                          
                                          ###To change text and background color of the `Select` box ###
                                          .dataTables_length select {
                                          color: #0E334A;
                                          background-color: #0E334A
                                          }
                                          
                                          ###To change text and background color of the `Search` box ###
                                          .dataTables_filter input {
                                          color: #0E334A;
                                          background-color: #0E334A
                                          }
                                          
                                          thead {
                                          color: #ffffff;
                                          }
                                          
                                          tbody {
                                          color: #000000;
                                          }
                                          
                                          "


                    )
  ),
                          
                          h4("Tableau de resultats"),
                          dataTableOutput("tab_res"),
                          
                          hr(),
                          
                          
                          h4("Meilleur modele"),
                          dataTableOutput("best_mod")
                          
                          
                        )
                        
                      )
             ),  
             
             tabPanel("Code & Donnees", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("database"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          h3("Affichage des donnees"),
                          
                          radioButtons(inputId = "Display1",
                                       label = "",
                                       choices = c("preview", "str","summary"),
                                       selected = "preview"),
                          
                          hr(),
                          
                          h3("Affichage du code"),
                          
                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "CodeR",
                                             label = "",
                                             choices = c("Afficher le code R" = "R1"))
                          
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             
             tabPanel("Graphiques", fluid = TRUE, icon = icon("chart-line"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          h3("Choix du modele"),
                          
                          radioButtons(inputId = "Display2",
                                       label = "",
                                       choices = c("Modele 1", "Modele 2","Modele 3","Modele 4"),
                                       selected = "Modele 1"),
                          
                          hr(),
                          
                          h3("Sauvegarder le graphique"),
                          
                          selectInput(inputId = "ExportGraph",
                                      label = "Choisir le format",
                                      choices = c("PNG", "JPEG","BMP"),
                                      selected = "PNG"),
                          
                          downloadButton("downloadData2", "Download")
                          
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             
             navbarMenu("Plus d'informations", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                        tabPanel("ÃƒÂ‰tude", fluid = TRUE,
                                 fluidRow(
                                   column(6,
                                          h4(p("RÃƒÂ©sumÃƒÂ©")),
                                          h5(p("Cette ÃƒÂ©tude a ÃƒÂ©tÃƒÂ© rÃƒÂ©alisÃƒÂ©e au cours d'un stage de fin d'ÃƒÂ©tudes en deuxiÃƒÂ¨me annÃƒÂ©e de Master DSMS (Data Science et ModÃƒÂ©lisation Statistique) ÃƒÂ  l'UniversitÃƒÂ© de Bretagne Sud. Le stage s'est dÃƒÂ©roulÃƒÂ© au sein du LMBA (Laboratoire de MathÃƒÂ©matiques de Bretagne Atlantique) sur une pÃƒÂ©riode de six mois."),
                                             p("Le sujet du stage ÃƒÂ©tait le suivant : Ã‚Â« Automatisation d'une procÃƒÂ©dure de sÃƒÂ©lection de modÃƒÂ¨les dans le cadre du Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es Ã‚Â»."),
                                             p("Au cours d'un projet prÃƒÂ©cÃƒÂ©dent, un outil avait ÃƒÂ©tÃƒÂ© contruit afin d'ajuster un modÃƒÂ¨le (de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es) sur des donnÃƒÂ©es et de collecter certaines informations associÃƒÂ©es ÃƒÂ  celui-ci. L'objectif de notre stage ÃƒÂ©tait donc d'ÃƒÂ©prouver l'outil dÃƒÂ©jÃƒÂ  existant, d'augmenter sa robustesse et son niveau de gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ricitÃƒÂ© et enfin d'automatiser la procÃƒÂ©dure complÃƒÂ¨te de sÃƒÂ©lection de modÃƒÂ¨les."),
                                             p("Cette interface Shiny est en quelque sorte la mise en forme de nos travaux."),
                                             p("Les dÃƒÂ©tails qui sont propres ÃƒÂ  notre programme sont rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ©rencÃƒÂ©s dans l'onglet intitulÃƒÂ© Ã‚Â« DÃƒÂ©tails Ã‚Â».")
                                          )
                                   ),
                                   column(6,
                                          h4(p("Le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es")),
                                          h5(p("Si l'on se rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ¨re aux travaux effectuÃƒÂ©s par FLOURENT (2019) dans le domaine du Smart Farming (l'agriculture de prÃƒÂ©cision), on peut dire que le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est une approche qui se situe ÃƒÂ  mi-chemin entre les approches dÃƒÂ®tes Ã‚Â« Black Box Ã‚Â» et Ã‚Â« White Box Ã‚Â»."),
                                             p("Le type de modÃƒÂ¨le appelÃƒÂ© Ã‚Â« Black Box Ã‚Â» fait en grande partie rÃƒÂ©fÃƒÂ©rence aux modÃƒÂ¨les classiques du Machine Learning (rÃƒÂ©seaux de neurones .). D'aprÃƒÂ¨s GORCZYCA et al (2018), VALLETTA et al. (2017), MA et al. (2014) et IP et al. (2018), la popularitÃƒÂ© de ces modÃƒÂ¨les peut s'expliquer par leur facilitÃƒÂ© d'utilisation, ainsi que par la diversitÃƒÂ© des problÃƒÂ¨mes pouvant ÃƒÂªtre rÃƒÂ©solus grÃƒÂ¢ce ÃƒÂ  de tels algorithmes. NÃƒÂ©anmoins ces modÃƒÂ¨les contiennent peu de connaissances a priori. Par consÃƒÂ©quent, les outils basÃƒÂ©s sur ce type de modÃƒÂ¨les sont peu informatifs d'un point de vue biologique (TAN et GILBERT (2003), SHAVLIK et al. (1995), HUBBARD et REINHARDT (1998)). Il faut ÃƒÂ©galement noter qu'il est nÃƒÂ©cessaire d'apprendre les paramÃƒÂ¨tres de ces modÃƒÂ¨les ÃƒÂ  partir de beaucoup de donnÃƒÂ©es et ceci dans le but de pallier l'absence d'expertise biologique (DUMPALA et al. (2017))"),
                                             p("ÃƒÂ€ l'inverse, les modÃƒÂ¨les Ã‚Â« White Box Ã‚Â» correspondent ÃƒÂ  des modÃƒÂ¨les mÃƒÂ©canistes rÃƒÂ©alistes (VAZQUEZ-CRUZ et al. (2014)). Si l'on se penche sur les travaux de BASTIANELLI et SAUVANT (1997) et MARTIN et SAUVANT (2010), la construction de modÃƒÂ¨les mÃƒÂ©canistes rÃƒÂ©alistes est une tÃƒÂ¢che complexe menant gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ralement ÃƒÂ  un modÃƒÂ¨le contenant un grand nombre d'ÃƒÂ©quations et de paramÃƒÂ¨tres ÃƒÂ  dÃƒÂ©terminer. Ce type de modÃƒÂ¨le nÃƒÂ©cessite d'avoir beaucoup de connaissances concernant le systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ©."),
                                             p("On cite une nouvelle fois les travaux de FLOURENT : Ã‚Â« Le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es consiste ÃƒÂ  intÃƒÂ©grer des connaissances concernant la dynamique du systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ© via la construction d'un modÃƒÂ¨le mathÃƒÂ©matique et ÃƒÂ  utiliser ensuite des donnÃƒÂ©es pour ajuster les paramÃƒÂ¨tres du modÃƒÂ¨le construit Ã‚Â». On peut aussi reprendre les travaux de FRENOD (2017), ROUSSEAU et NODET (2013), SACKS et al. (2007) et WANG et al. (2010), et dire que le Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨les-DonnÃƒÂ©es consiste ÃƒÂ  construire un modÃƒÂ¨le mathÃƒÂ©matique parcimonieux, correspondant ÃƒÂ  une synthÃƒÂ¨se mathÃƒÂ©matique du systÃƒÂ¨me ÃƒÂ©tudiÃƒÂ©.")
                                          )
                                   ))
                                 
                        ),
                        
                        tabPanel("DÃƒÂ©tails", fluid = TRUE,
                                 fluidRow(
                                   column(6,
                                          #br(),
                                          h4(p("ModÃƒÂ¨les")),
                                          h5(p("Notre programme comporte trois types de modÃƒÂ¨les et quatre modÃƒÂ¨les diffÃƒÂ©rents. Deux modÃƒÂ¨les de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es (les modÃƒÂ¨les 1 et 2), un modÃƒÂ¨le de type rÃƒÂ©seau de neurones (le modÃƒÂ¨le 3) et un modÃƒÂ¨le de type linÃƒÂ©aire (le modÃƒÂ¨le 4).")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("ParamÃƒÂ¨tres")),
                                          h5(p("Le premier modÃƒÂ¨le de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est composÃƒÂ© de trois paramÃƒÂ¨tres ajustÃƒÂ©s. Le second modÃƒÂ¨le de type Couplage ModÃƒÂ¨le-DonnÃƒÂ©es est composÃƒÂ© de deux paramÃƒÂ¨tres ajustÃƒÂ©s et d'un paramÃƒÂ¨tre fixe. Le modÃƒÂ¨le de type rÃƒÂ©seau de neurones est composÃƒÂ© de trois couches cachÃƒÂ©es (la premiÃƒÂ¨re et la troisiÃƒÂ¨me couches comportent trois neurones, la deuxiÃƒÂ¨me couche compte six neurones).")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Informations")),
                                          h5(p("Notre outil permet de collecter un certain nombre d'informations sur chacun des modÃƒÂ¨les comme l'erreur d'apprentissage, l'erreur test ou encore le temps de calcul. Certaines de ces informations nous sont utiles pour calculer notre indicateur de comparaison."))
                                          
                                          #hr(),
                                          
                                   ),
                                   column(6,
                                          #br(),
                                          h4(p("Indicateur")),
                                          h5(p("Notre indicateur de comparaison se base sur cinq informations diffÃƒÂ©rentes, ÃƒÂ  savoir : l'erreur test, l'erreur d'apprentissage, le temps de calcul, la complexitÃƒÂ© du modÃƒÂ¨le et la ratio.")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Programme")),
                                          h5(p("Le programme, sur la base de l'indicateur, renvoie le Ã‚Â« meilleur Ã‚Â» modÃƒÂ¨le ainsi qu'un tableau de rÃƒÂ©sultats avec un certain nombre d'infomations. L'utilisateur a la possibilitÃƒÂ© de sÃƒÂ©lectionner les modÃƒÂ¨les qu'il souhaite comparer, de choisir diffÃƒÂ©rents ratios (taille des donnÃƒÂ©es d'apprentissage et de test) ainsi que les poids associÃƒÂ©s (alphas) aux paramÃƒÂ¨tres de l'indicateur.")),
                                          br(),
                                          h4(p("Poids associÃƒÂ©s")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 1 : poids associÃƒÂ© au ratio")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 2 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  l'erreur d'apprentissage")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 3 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  l'erreur test")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 4 : poids associÃƒÂ© au temps de calcul")),
                                          h5(p("alpha 5 : poids associÃƒÂ© ÃƒÂ  la complexitÃƒÂ© du modÃƒÂ¨le"))
                                          
                                   )
                                 ),
                                 br(),
                                 hr(),
                                 h6(      
                                   p(
                                     a("UniversitÃƒÂ© de Bretagne Sud", 
                                       href = "https://www.univ-ubs.fr/fr/index.html"),
                                     br(),
                                     br(),
                                     a("Laboratoire de MathÃƒÂ©matiques de Bretagne Atlantique", 
                                       href = "http://www.lmba-math.fr/"))),
                                 
                                 h6("ConÃƒÂ§u avec",
                                    img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shiny.png", height = "30px"),
                                    "par",
                                    img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray.png", height = "30px"),
                                    ".")
                        )
             )
  )
)
```

and here is the server code :

```
work_dir_3 <- "C:\\Users\\François\\Desktop\\SHINY"
setwd(work_dir_3)
getwd()

source("procedure_finale_shiny.R", local = TRUE)

#res1 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[1]]) 
#res2 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[2]])

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {
    procedure_finale_shiny(
      input$SliderAlpha1, input$SliderAlpha2, input$SliderAlpha3, input$SliderAlpha4, input$SliderAlpha5,
      c(input$SliderRatio1, input$SliderRatio2,input$SliderRatio3, input$SliderRatio4, input$SliderRatio5),
      as.numeric(input$ModeleFinder))
  })
  
  output$best_mod <- renderTable({ results()[[1]] })
  output$tab_res <- renderTable({ results()[[2]] })
}
```

I should have a result table but instead, I have nothing. I don't know where the error comes from...

Here is my shiny app (without the server part): https://milesfrancois.shinyapps.io/shiny/

If you have any advice or methods to control the results and find why there are no results?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, your example is way too long and is not reproducible because we don't have access to your files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to make an example that is **reproducible** and **minimal**.